# how to get an SDP record for bluetooth service?

Tags: bluetooth, winsock, sdp

I'm new to both winsock and bluetooth programming. I need to develop a bluetooth service to run on a pc.
Looking at the MSDN library they say to use WSASetService(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362921%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to publish a service.

The problem is that the WSAQUERYSET(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362920%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure, that has to be passed to WSASetService, needs a binary SDP record and i don't know how to get it.

In the Windows embedded section of the MSDN library they describe a procedure to obtain an SDP record using [Bthnscreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495837.aspx).

I installed Windows CE 6 to use this tool but i can't find it in the install directory nor in the entire system.

How can i get an SDP record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay me to create it for you?  No I'm kidding -- unless you need expert help.  I'm maintainer of the 32feet.NET Bluetooth library for .NET.  We include full SDP record parsing, creating, and diagnostic dumping.  You should be able to create your record with our `ServiceRecordBuilder` class and then have it converted to binary form with method `ServiceRecordCreator.CreateServiceRecord`.  See some documentation in the "Bluetooth SDP — Service Discovery Protocol" section in [32feet.NET -- User Guide](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20--%20User%20Guide.html)

Comment: Hi alanjmcf :)
After spending another day to find a solution i decided to use 32feet library and I had already read some of your posts and documents on your site. Just curious..do you know why bthnscreate tool is just included in win CE and not on windows??Thanks for your reply!